# On success slidedown div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//foreach loop
    <div id="someid" class="chkbox">
    //chkbox code
    </div>
//foreach loop ends


$('.chk').change(function(e) { //Todo active inactive
           e.preventDefault();
           var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
           if($('.chk').is(':checked'))
                var active = 1;  // checked
           else
                var active = 0;  // unchecked
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
               url: '/Home/chktodo', //controller Home action chktodo
               data: 'id='+id+ '&active='+active,
               success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    }
           });
       });
```

on success how I can slidedown perticular div with class "chkbox"(as checkbox is in foreach loop,there will be many checkbox as per data from database)

Comment: If there are multiple `.chk` and `.chkbox` elements, what's the connection between them in the markup, or are you trying to just slide down all of them?

Comment: on click i am changing value in DB, and on success i want them to slide down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use JQuery class selector:

```
 $('.chkbox').slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
 $('div.chkbox').slideDown();
```